# ACPI errors at boot

Tags: boot, kernel, suspend, 22.04, acpi

Using Ubuntu 22.04 on kernel 5.15.0-37-generic, I suddenly get numerous errors during boot.

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR04._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR05._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR06._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR07._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

After this started appearing, the suspend function started acting weird. When entering suspend, it turns off the display, immediately turns back on and stays on. If I suspend again, it does it successfully. But upon wake up, it doesn't prompt for a password, it just goes straight to the desktop.

I found an older kernel bug report, which patched it in 5.12, but it seems it was reverted back. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213023

Comment: Having almost the exact same errors on 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-39-generic. Only the ACPI Error at the end is somewhat different. Also just before these errors occur some additional lines are logged as well (dmesg) and maybe give some hint to the cause? Pastebin [here...](https://pastebin.com/2H4d8WUQ)

Comment: Those tend to be benign. It requires either a bios or a kernel update to fix this. Problem is outside of the reach of Ubuntu/AskUbuntu. You can suppress these by adding `acpi=off intremap=no_x2apic_optout nox2apic` to grub config.

Comment: oh that will disable acpi.

Answer (score 2):

My bios was recently updated by dell automatically, then I see these errors at boot. Dual Boot Windows 11 (rarely used) and Ubuntu 22.04LTS. It's working fine so far its just a nag for me. I assume its the Bios.

Comment: Mike, does this error still stands for you? I also have a DELL bios system, and it is getting this error every time I try to load the 22.04 LTS on kernels that are not in the recovery mode (when in recovery mode it does work though).